# increment odd or even numbers in excel/openoffice calc?

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc

Im trying to increment in 1st column every even number by 1 and the 2nd column increment all odd numbers by 1.

what I manually have done so far:

```
48  4
4   49
49  4
4   50
50  4
2   51
51  2
2   52
52  2
2   53
```

as you can see in the 1st column every even number is incremented by 1 and in the 2nd column every odd number is incremented by 1. How can i do that automatically?

I mostly use open office calc, but I also have excel so either solution for both or one of them would be great!

Comment: every odd row in the 3rd column should be incremented
every even row in the 2nd column should be incremented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need code for this, it can be done using in-cell formulas.

When you want to increment all even numbers by one:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(A1 / 2, 0) * 2 + 1
```

When you want to increment all odd numbers by one:

```
=ROUNDUP(A1 / 2, 0) * 2
```

...where A1 is the name of the cell. Then just drag down the first row to extend the series into the entire column.

Comment: is it possible you could make an example on howto automatically do my example?

Comment: I can't see a pattern in your example... sorry!